# Testing lists in GO

Tags: arrays, unit-testing, testing, go

I'm trying to implement a test in GO. But I'm struggling with the list's syntax inside the struct.

```
package primeFactor

import "testing"

var testCases = []struct {
    p        int
    expected []int
}{
    {15, [3,5]},
    {26, [2,13]},
    {37, [37]},
    {42, [2,3,7]},
}

func TestPrimeFactor(t *testing.T) {
    for _, test := range testCases {
        observed := PrimeFactor(test.p)
        if observed != test.expected {
            t.Error("For p = %d, expected %t. Got %t.",
                test.p, test.expected, observed)
        }
    }
}
```

The output error I have is:

```
expected ']', found ','
: expected operand, found '{'
: expected ';', found 'for'
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toni's answer addresses your specific problem but to address the other issue of comparing slices you'll want to use [reflect.DeepEqual](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual)

Check out this example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    observed := []int{1, 2}
    expected := []int{1, 3}

    if reflect.DeepEqual(observed, expected) {
        fmt.Println("Slices are the same")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Slices are different")
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_JRQ5bqmJf

Comment: Note: reflecting can be 2x to orders of magnitude slower. If you are concerned about performance, you might want a simple for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you wrote that in the first place? That's not Go syntax. From [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec):

> A slice literal describes the entire underlying array literal. Thus, the length and capacity of a slice literal are the maximum element index plus one. A slice literal has the form
>
> ```
> []T{x1, x2, … xn}
> ```

So, in your case:

```
var testCases = []struct {
    p        int
    expected []int
}{
    {15, []int{3, 5}},
    {26, []int{2, 13}},
    {37, []int{37}},
    {42, []int{2, 3, 7}},
}
```

The spec is pretty readable and less scary than one might think. You may want to give it a full look and keep it close for reference.

Comment: Noted. Thank you. But it seems that I need to compare one element at time. "slice con only be compared to nill"

Answer (score 2):

...and for completeness, here's just a simple example of writing your own function that your test can call to compare the slices:

```
func slicesMatch(a, b []int) bool {
    la := len(a)
    lb := len(b)

    if la != lb {
        return false
    }

    for i := 0; i < la; i++ {
        if a[i] != b[i] {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

<kbd>[View it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/w9lYC3lfZ4)</kbd>

Comment: +1. I've been trying to learn Go for a few months and especially interested in what the community considers "idiomatic." Is it typical to avoid the `reflect` package for just this simple use case? Or is your post just "for completeness" as you said?

Comment: While in examples `reflect.DeepEqual` works (and will work very quickly with small slices), the bigger your slice gets, the slower it will get. It jumps through all sorts of hoops to return you a result because its trying to determine the types used in the slice and how to compare them. Whereas, you already know the type of the slices (`int`), so you can fine tune your own version for your use case. Some people consider it personal preference .. but I think you'll find a lot of Gophers prefer speed.

Comment: ...if you're worried about the "custom written" aspect of it, don't be - utility functions like this will grow over time for you. Simply place them in their own package and reference them again in future and that issue goes away :)